# Conditional Probability $P(B| A\cap B) = 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$P(B|A\cap B) = 1$?

I'm a little confused about the probability of $B$ occurring given that $B\cap A$ occurred. If $B\cap A$ happens, does this guarantee $B$'s occurrence or must we consider the possibility that $B^c$ has not been addressed?

Thank you!

Comment: If you *know* that events $A$ and $B$ have both happened then you *know* that event $B$ has happened.

Comment: @Henry I can see "how" that makes sense but my question lied in the meaning of $A \cap B$. I wasn't sure if this meant the part that both $A$ and $B$ shared has happened or if all of $A$ and all of $B$ has happened.

Comment: Neither really, but more the former than the latter.  If a clock has struck 12  and a person has entered the room, this implies a person has entered the room, but not that everybody in the world has entered the room.

Comment: That's a great example thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)\ne0$, then

$$
\mathsf{P}(B\mid A\cap B)=\frac{\mathsf{P}(B\cap A\cap B)}{\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)}=\frac{\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathsf{P}(A\cap B)}=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

That the event $B \cap A$ has occurred implies that event $B$ has occurred as well as event $A$. We don't need to consider $B^c$. It's clear that $P(B|B) = 1,$ and $P(B|A \cap B) = 1$ as well.

Comment: So $B\cap A$ in this sense is not the same as $B$ intersect $A$ where $A$ and $B$ are subsets with $n$, $k$ elements respectively? i.e. does $B \cap A$ mean that both $B$ and $A$ have happened or that the elements that both $A$ and $B$ share have happened.

Comment: They're similar. The occurrence of event $B \cap A$ means that some outcome that satisfies both $B$ and $A$ has occurred.

Example: Say $A$ is the event that, upon flipping a coin twice, we never get tails. We can represent $A$ as $\{HH, HT, TH\}$. Say $B$ is the event that we get two of the same side in a row, and so we represent $B$ as $\{HH, TT\}$. Then an outcome of $HH$ is in $B \cap A$ (and, in this case, is the only outcome in $B \cap A$).